# JSON array splitting React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON array in my state and I want to use the other half of it. For example if the size of the JSON array is 10, I am interested in to access the later 5 values. How can I achieve that? I have tried many solutions but I always end up getting errors.
I am working with React JS.
So I was using map function but I am unable to fulfill my condition.

```js
  data.map((item, index) => {
```

I am unable to use reduce or filter I tried that also.

Comment: did you try to use `slice` method? you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SaeedShamloo mentioned `slice` method will be sufficient here

```
data.slice(Math.floor(data.length/2), data.length).map(item => )
```

Comment: data.form.slice(Math.floor(0), data.form.length/2).map((item, index) => { })
Is this the right thing to do if I want to access the first half?

Comment: The op question was `For example if the size of the JSON array is 10, I am interested in to access the later 5 values`

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` by array indexes.

```js
const data = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

const res = data.filter((_, idx, arr) => idx >= arr.length / 2);

console.log(res);


// Alternatively
const res2 = data.slice(-data.length/2);

console.log(res2);
```